# DQL to SQL conversion

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I have a DQL query which is working fine:

```
$query = $queryBuilder
                         ->innerJoin('i.instsummary', 's')    
                         ->innerJoin('i.address', 'a') 
                         ->innerJoin('i.insturl', 'u') 
                         ->select('s.instaffiliation,i.institutename,i.institutefeerange,i.instituterating,a.addressline1,a.addressline2,i.instituterating,'
                                 . 'i.instituteteachingtimings,s.instdescription,s.insttype,s.insteligibilitycriteria,u.instlogo,u.instbrochure')
                         ->where('s.instaffiliation = :instaffiliation')
                         ->orderBy('i.instituterating')
                         ->setParameter('instaffiliation', $data)
                         ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I need to convert this query into SQL. As I am new to this can anyone please help me?

Comment: You might want to review a good SQL tutorial.  If you knew even basic SQL it would be fairly obvious how to transform the above code to a raw query.  Actually, going in the other direction, i.e. query to code, is harder in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

To get the SQL from your query builder object you just need to call `getSQL()` method like

```
echo $queryBuilder->innerJoin(..)...->getQuery()->getSQL();
```

For DQL

```
echo $queryBuilder->innerJoin(..)...->getQuery()->getDQL();
```